# Using SCSS variables in CSS Modules

Tags: reactjs, sass, webpack, css-modules, react-css-modules

I've a `_color.scss` file which consists of 400 colors as variables. And I've like 20 components which needs this color variables in their styles.

I'm using SCSS + CSS Modules to construct my styles. As of now, I'm importing this `_color.scss` in each and every component's `style.scss`.

Example:

**component1.scss**

```
@import "color.scss";
```

**component2.scss**

```
@import "color.scss";
```

**component3.scss**

```
@import "color.scss";
```

Previously, when I was using SCSS standalone, I'll import the `color.scss` to my `index.scss` and import all the other styles below it. By this, the variables will be available across all the components.

Example:

```
//index.scss
@import "color.scss";
@import "component1.scss";
@import "component2.scss";
@import "component3.scss";
```

Now, all the variables under `_color.scss` will be available under `component1.scss`, `component2.scss` and `component3.scss`.

Is there a way to do something similar to this with `CSS Modules + SCSS`? A single place to declare global varibales?

Answer (score 5):

The way I'm using now looks pretty clean. So, I'm sharing it to all.

Use [sass-resources-loader](https://github.com/shakacode/sass-resources-loader)

This will include the `@import` to all your `.scss` files making the variables and mixins available across all the `scss` files while using `css modules`.

The **webpack@2.x.x** config

```
...
    module: {
      rules: [
        {
          test: /\.scss$/,
          loaders: [
            'style-loader',
            'css-loader?modules&importLoaders=1&localIdentName=[path][name]__[local]__[hash:base64:10]',
            'sass-loader',
            'sass-resources-loader',
            'import-glob-loader',
            'postcss-loader',
          ],
        },
     },
     plugins: [
       new webpack.LoaderOptionsPlugin({
        options: {
          postcss: [
            autoprefixer(),
          ],
          sassResources: [
            './app/constants/_style-variables.scss', //include your scss imports here
          ],
          context: path.resolve(__dirname, '../../')
        }
      })
     ]
...
```